# Connecting a monitor to laptop via USB-C (Thunderbolt)

Tags: monitors, display-port, usb-c, thunderbolt, cable

I have these digital connectors for connecting external monitors:

1. HDMI (version: 2.0)
2. USB-C (version: Thunderbolt 3)

While the HDMI I would better like to leave untouched for connecting my TV.

Thus, leaving me only the Thunderbolt port, if there is such a cable?

Answer (score 0):

I have found in our local shop available this cable:

**[Axagon RVC-DPC USB-C > DP CABLE 1.8M](https://axagon.eu/en/produkty/rvc-dpc) (link to manufacturer)**

Before buying, please look at your USB-C type below to make sure it is capable for DisplayPort output:

[image: USB-C types and its ability for DisplayPort]

Red means no DisplayPort output, and green DisplayPort capable.

Basic specs on the following picture, look at the link above however for details:

[image: Axagon USBC -> DisplayPort cable]

Since I have Thunderbolt 3 according to the table, it works like a charm.

Hope it helps someone looking for the same solution.